# script not working when invoked via cron

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I have created a script `script.sh` which contains

```
./ecc start pricingUpdater & >> /home/eceuser/Muthu/details/Latest.txt
```

where `ecc` is another script.

If I run the script manually by simply invoking `./script.sh` I am able to start the utility:

```
Starting Oracle Communication Elastic Charging Controller 11.2.0.1 ...

-- Node 'pricingUpdater' started with PID 10705
^[[1m===>^[[m [{GridEventImpl
status: true
node: PricingUPdater node pricingUpdater on Host 10.180.85.16
details: [pid:10705, state:running]
}]
```

but if I try to run the same script via `crontab` I get:

```
Starting Oracle Communication Elastic Charging Controller 11.2.0.1 ...
```

so the utility is not started.

Comment: have you tried full path to ecc in your script?

Comment: I think you mean `./ecc .. pricingUpdater >> ...Latest.txt &`

Comment: no I mean full path like /this/is/full/path/to/ecc

Comment: I tried with giving full put also its not working

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are running the cron jobs with user which doesn't have permission to edit or create `/home/eceuser/Muthu/details/Latest.txt` file